# c++ cli или где типизация?

Tags: c#, c++

Перевожу код из c++ cli в c#. Есть фрагмент когда

```
void method() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 65536; i++) ]
        variable[i] = method1(i);
}
```

Как можно увидеть, в method1 падает значения типа `int`, НО, method1 принимает значение типа `wchar_t variable2` и в реализации метода, создается переменная с присвоением данного типа `int variable3 = variable2`
Это как так получается, у меня C# ругается на такое: Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из "int" в "char".

Вопрос, в c++ идет автоматическое преобразование, или преобразования никакого нет и просто передается `int` значение, что происходит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ разрешает неявные преобразования с потерей данных. C# разрешает некоторые неявные преобразование без потери данных.